# C code gives different return value, depending on usage of "puts("..")

Tags: c

I'm doing some C programming and got a problem, I haven't done a lot of C programming so it's probably something stupid, excuse me then. But I just can't figure out why this code block gives different output depending on if I execute the line `//puts("is_in_group called");` or not.

```
GHashTable *is_in_group(GPtrArray *groups, char *city, int elements_in_groups){

    //puts("is_in_group called"); If I uncomment this line, the function works, but otherwise it doesn't

    GHashTable *temp_set = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < elements_in_groups; i++){

        temp_set = g_ptr_array_index(groups, i);
        if(g_hash_table_contains(temp_set, city)){
            printf("Found: %s\n",city );
            return temp_set;

        }
    }
    printf("City: %s not found\n", city);

    return temp_set;
}
```

OUTPUT WITH `//puts("is_in_group called");`:

```
Added:
Wheeling
Sumter
----
is_in_group called
Found: Wheeling
is_in_group called
Found: Sumter
```

OUTPUT WITHOUT `puts("is_in_group called")`;

```
Added:
Wheeling
Sumter
----
City: Wheeling not found
City: Sumter not found
```

If I move around my puts/prints I can get other combinations of the output, for example one found and one not.

Full code here, but I don't expect anyone to look at it. The whole parser() part is 100% so nothing wrong there.
http://pastebin.com/spcxMF76
Here is how the function is used:

```
/*runs kruskal's algorithm on @param edges and stores
 a minimal spanning tree in @param min_tree*/
void run_kruskal(Edge edges[], GPtrArray *result)
{
    int elements_in_groups = 0;
    GPtrArray *groups = g_ptr_array_new();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        char *city_a = edges[0].city_a;
        char *city_b = edges[1000].city_b;


        // Check if city A and B are already in a group
        GHashTable *t1 = g_hash_table_new (NULL, compare_strings);
        g_hash_table_add(t1, city_a);
        g_ptr_array_add (groups, t1);
        elements_in_groups++;
        GHashTable *t2 = g_hash_table_new (NULL, compare_strings);
        g_hash_table_add(t2, city_b);

        g_ptr_array_add (groups, t2);

        elements_in_groups++;
        GHashTable *group_A = is_in_group(groups, city_a, elements_in_groups);

        GHashTable *group_B = is_in_group(groups, city_b, elements_in_groups);


    }




}
```

Comment: It looks like you're invoking undefined behaviour due to a bug in your code. I would suggest checking your `g_ptr_array_index()` and `g_hash_table_contains()` functions for errors such as buffer overflows or uninitialized variables.

Comment: are you sure the only difference between the two builds/runs was the commenting of that line ? No other code was changed ? No different compilation flags ? No input was different ? No external resources were modified ?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Yeah must be something like that, but still can't figure out how that line could effect that. Those functions are from the GLIB library which is fairly well used, so doubt this could be a bug on their side.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Everything is exactly the same. Only thing changed is that line.

Comment: In that case, we probably need to see more than just this function. Can you create a minimal working code that exhibits the same behavior ? Or at least show the code that calls this function ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Added some code extra. Thanks :D

Comment: Not specifying a hash function in the calls to `g_hash_table_new` is probably wrong, because it will hash based on the string pointer rather than its contents.

Comment: @interjay Did that, and even replaced all my char pointers with glib's GString, so there wouldn't be any problem with going between those. Still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going over your code, a few issues I spotted that could explain the behavior you see :

1. You don't allocate enough memory when copying strings in the `parse` function :

   ```
   temp_copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(temp1));
   strcpy(temp_copy, temp1);
   edges[index].city_a = temp_copy;
   ```

   You need to also allocate memory for the `'\0'` terminator :

   ```
   temp_copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp1) + 1));
   ```

   As a side note, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 (by definition), so there's no need to mention it explicitly.
2. Your `compare_edges` function does not follow the requirements of [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort). You don't cover the case where both edges are equal :

   ```
   return e1 -> weight > e2->weight ? 1 : -1;
   ```

   Something like this is better :

   ```
   return (e1->weight > e2->weight) ? 1 : ((e1->weight < e2->weight) ? -1 : 0);
   ```
3. When you create hash tables (using [`g_hash_table_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-new)) in the `run_kruskal` function, you don't specify a hash function :

   ```
   GHashTable *t1 = g_hash_table_new (NULL, compare_strings);
   ```

   Instead, use the built-in [`g_str_hash`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-str-hash) and [`g_str_equal`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-str-equal) functions for strings :

   ```
   GHashTable *t1 = g_hash_table_new (g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
   ```

There might be other issues lurking in the code, but try fixing these first, and see if things improve.

Comment: Thanks for putting time into this, I fixed all those yesterday. But still had the same problem. However I rewrote that function and now somehow I don't seem to get that problem.